# How can I edit an item in a list within a list?

Tags: python, list, indexing

I'm trying to simulate a social network in python, and what follows is the initial build of the network. This works exactly as I want it to, in that it will randomly connect the two people in the network with a 25% chance, and if it connects the first person with the second person it will always connect the second person with the first person (and vice versa) and then I can print the network to see who is connected to who.

The problem I'm having is that I need to be able to add as many people as I want, but this involves putting a list inside of a list and I can't figure out how to change the value of an item of a list inside of a list without defining each list first. This is the code

```
from random import randint  

network = []
person0 = range(0,2)
person1 = range(0,2)

for x in range(len(person0)):
    for randint(0,100)<25 and person0[x]!=0:
        person0[x]="connected"
    else:
        person0[x]=0

for y in range(len(person1)):
if randint(0,100)<25 and person1[y]!=1:
    person1[y]="connected"
else:
    person1[y]=0

if person0[1]=="connected":
    person1[0]="connected"
if person1[0]=="connected":
    person0[1]="connected"

network.append(person0)
network.append(person1)
print network
```

This returns either [[0, 'connected'],['connected', 0]] or [[0, 0],[0, 0]], both of which are acceptable, but I don't want to manually add person2, person3, person4, etc., manually test each comparison, and manually append them. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the list(`network`) first, and then make the connections

```
from random import randint  

network = []

numberofpersons = 3
network = [range(numberofpersons) for i in range(numberofpersons)]

for i in range(numberofpersons):
    for j in range(numberofpersons):
        if randint(0,100)<25 and j!=i:
            network[i][j]="connected"
            network[j][i]="connected"
        else:
            network[i][j]=0
            network[j][i]=0


print network  
# [[0, 0, 'connected'], [0, 0, 'connected'], ['connected', 'connected', 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking for is to create the lists in a separate loop:

```
network = [range(N) for i in range(N)]
```

Then `network[i]` refers to a single person. `network[0]` is equivalent to `person0`.

Here's the whole thing.

```
from random import randint  

N = 2
network = [range(N) for i in range(N)]

for y in range(N):
    person = network[y]
    for x in range(len(person)):
        if randint(0,100)<25 and network[x]:
            person[x] = "connected"
        else:
            person[x] = 0

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        if network[i][j] == "connected":
            network[j][i] = "connected"

print network
```